# HTML form upload for ODT files / MIME type for *.odt

Tags: html, forms, input, mime-types

I'm looking for a HTML form upload just for ODT-Files. I need to know the parameter for `accept`.

```html
<form method="post" action="upload.php" >
      <input type="file" name="file_upload" accept="" />
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a search in *stackoverflow* I found the I have to define the correct MIME type.

For **ODT** the **MIME type** is `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text`

---

The HTML code has to look like that:

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" >
      <input type="file" name="file_upload" 
             accept="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text" />
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's MIME type actually. Also, if you do have a file you want to know the type of, right-click and "Properties" will usually tell you.